# Получение суммы

Tags: php, суммирование, sql

Есть поле points и запрос вида:

```
$db->query("SELECT `points` FROM `users`");
```

Также в бд есть 5 юзеров например, у всех разные значения в **points**.

Как получить общую сумму по полю **points** у всех пользователей?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться SQL-функцией [SUM()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

```
$db->query("SELECT SUM(`points`) FROM `users`");
```